# No converter for [class java.lang.String] with preset Content-Type 'text/plain'

Tags: java, spring, http, servlets

I'm trying to return a formatted string from a endpoint with spring, with the following code

```
private static class Json
            implements Serializable {
        private final String value;

        public Json(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Json{" +
                    "value='" + value + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/description", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HttpEntity<String> retrieveDescription() {

        String text = this.retrieveDescription();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

        return new HttpEntity<String>(text, headers);
    }
```

But when I execute the request I get the following error

> No converter for [class java.lang.String] with preset Content-Type 'text/plain'

I've tried returning the Json class but still the same problem
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you return a `HttpEntity`? I would have expected an `ResponseEntity<String>` or just a `String` as return-type.

Comment: When I return just a String I don't get the formatting I want. Do you know how can I return a String formatting \n and \t?

Comment: I get this response instead of formatting the string correctly"(\n\tNOT (\n\t\t(\n\t\t\t"